# Jacobi Identity and Lie Algebra

Tags: group-theory, lie-algebras

How can I demonstrate the Jacobi identity:

\begin{equation}
[S_{i}, [S_{j},S_{k}]] + [S_{j}, [S_{k},S_{i}]] + [S_{k}, [S_{i},S_{j}]] = 0 ~,
\end{equation}

using the infinitesimal generators $S_{\kappa}$ for a continuous group, where the generators satisfies the Lie algebra, such that:

$$[S_{\alpha},S_{\beta}] = \sum_{\gamma} f_{\alpha \beta \gamma}S_{\gamma}$$

where $f_{\alpha \beta \gamma}$ are the structure constants ?

I was doing the following:

$$\begin{align*}
[S_{i}, [S_{j},S_{k}]] &+ [S_{j}, [S_{k},S_{i}]] + [S_{k}, [S_{i},S_{j}]] = \\
 &= 
[S_{i}, \sum_{l} f_{jkl}S_{l}] + [S_{j}, \sum_{l} f_{kil}S_{l}] + [S_{k}, \sum_{l} f_{ijl}S_{l}]\\
 &=   \sum_{l} f_{jkl} [S_{i}, S_{l}] + \sum_{l} f_{kil}[S_{j}, S_{l}] + \sum_{l} f_{ijl}[S_{k}, S_{l}]\\ 
&= \sum_{l} f_{jkl} \sum_{m} f_{ilm}S_{m} + \sum_{l} f_{kil}\sum_{n} f_{jln}S_{n}\\
&\qquad + \sum_{l} f_{ijl}\sum_{p} f_{klp}S_{p}\\ 
&=  \sum_{l,~m} f_{jkl} f_{ilm}S_{m} + \sum_{l,~n} f_{kil}f_{jln}S_{n} + \sum_{l,~p} f_{ijl}f_{klp}S_{p}\\
 &=  f_{jk}^{l} f_{il}^{m}~S_{m} + f_{ki}^{l}f_{jl}^{n}~S_{n} + f_{ij}^{l}f_{kl}^{p}~S_{p}
\end{align*}$$
I know that these structure constants are antisymmetric:

\begin{equation}
f_{\alpha \beta}^{\gamma} = - f_{\beta \alpha}^{\gamma} ~~.
\end{equation}

Are there a way to go further and show that the expression will be equal to zero ?

Comment: You can't "deduce" the Jacobi identity from antisymmetry of the structure constants. It's a fundamental property of the Lie bracket, and then implies additional conditions on the structure constants. In your notation, these conditions would be $f_{jk}^lf_{il}^m+f_{ki}^lf_{jl}^m+f_{ij}^lf_{kl}^m = 0$.

Comment: This is what I'm not getting. We can use the Jacobi identity to find the relation you just write, but, that also means that I could open the terms on the Jacobi identity and find out that would be zero, after all. Right? I would need to know something about the $f$'s to figure it out...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "I could open the terms on the Jacobi identity and find out that would be zero, after all." Suppose we pick a basis $S_i$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, then define $[S_i,S_j]=\sum_k f_{ijk}S_k$, and extend this by bilinearity to define a bracket on all of $\mathfrak{g}$. The point is that one can't just pick any antisymmetric $f$ here and get a consistent Lie bracket. In order for the Jacobi identity to be satisfied, the structure constants must satisfy an additional condition.

Comment: Yes. But, if I know the structure factors a priori, somehow, and open the three commutators, add them, that would be zero, right?

Comment: If by "opening the three commutators", you mean writing $[S_i,S_k] = S_iS_j-S_jS_i$ etc., then yes.

Answer (score 3):

The Jacobi identity can be derives formally by expanding $[S_i,S_j]=S_iS_j-S_jS_i$. Define the *associator* of $S_i,S_j,S_k$ by
$$
(S_i,S_j,S_k)=(S_iS_j)S_k-S_i(S_jS_k)
$$
This is zero if the product is associative. However, a direct computation shows that we always have
$$
[[S_i,S_j],S_k]+[[S_j,S_k],S_i]+[[S_k,S_i],S_j]]=
$$

$$
(S_i,S_j,S_k)+(S_j,S_k,S_i)+(S_k,S_i,S_j)-(S_j,S_i,S_k)-(S_i,S_k,S_j)-(S_k,S_j,S_i).
$$
In particular, the Jacobi identity holds if the associator is always zero (but also, if it is, say, nonzero and left-symmetric, and so on).

Comment: So, satisfying Jacobi identity depends on the associativity of the mathematical structure? All groups, by definition, follows $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$, therefore, all groups satisfies Jacobi identity?

Comment: @Ykmo-v You have to distinguish Lie groups and Lie algebras. For Lie algebras we deal with vector spaces. In my answer, $S_i$ is a linear operator. You are writing $a,b,c$ in the group, not in the vector space.

Comment: @Ykmo-v No, the generators of a group do not satisfy the Jacobi identity. We have to take the vectors of the Lie algebra to check the Jacobi identity, see your definition. If you write the Jacobi identity for $S_i,S_j,S_k$ (see your post), then these are vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Recapitulating @DietrichBurde's point, in different terms:

Again, emphatically, if we have a real or complex vector space $V$ with an anti-commutative binary (bilinear) operation $[,]$, this does not imply that $[,]$ satisfies the Jacobi identity. At this level of abstraction, the Jacobi identity must be *required*.

To see some sense in what the Jacobi asserts, rather than it just being "a formula", it asserts that the map $x\to \mathrm{ad}(x)$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism, where $\mathrm(ad)(x)(y)=[x,y]$. That is, it asserts/requires that $$
\mathrm{ad}(x)\circ\mathrm{ad}(y)-\mathrm{ad}(y)\circ\mathrm{ad}(x)
\;=\; \mathrm{ad}([x,y])
$$
The left-hand side is the natural Lie bracket $[A,B]=A\circ B-B\circ A$ inside the linear endomorphism algebra of $V$.

This also broaches the issue of possibly hoping to "open up" $[A,B]$ into $AB-BA$. This makes best sense if/when $A,B$ are elements of some associative algebra, such as square matrices. And, yes, if/when one has a vector subspace $V$ of square matrices of some size, closed under $[A,B]=AB-BA$, then it does make sense to "open up" the brackets, and, yes, one can prove by direct computation that the Jacobi identity holds.

The Jacobi identity also can be *proven* to hold when the vector space is the tangent space at the identity of a (real or complex) Lie group.

The two cases overlap because the space of square matrices is identifiable as the Lie algebra of the multiplicatively invertible matrices of that size.

EDIT: after a few minutes' foolling around, it's not so hard to make a three-dimensional algebra with a skew-symmetric operator $[,]$ which fails to satisfy the Jacobi identity. E.g., take basis $x,y,z$ and $[x,y]=x$, $[x,z]=y$, $[y,z]=0$. Then
$$
\Big(\mathrm{ad}(x)\circ\mathrm{ad}(y)-\mathrm{ad}(y)\circ\mathrm{ad}(x)\Big)(z)
\;=\; [x,[y,z]]-[y,[x,z]] \;=\; [x,0] - [y,y] \;=\; 0
$$
while
$$
[[x,y],z] \;=\; [x,z] \;=\; y \;\not=\; 0
$$